# Linq to XML work with repeatable nodes CRUD operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml, crud

I have an xml like this:

```
<Root>
 <MortgaginContracts>
   <ContractInfo>
       <PledgeType>3</PledgeType>
       <ContractType>0</ContractType>
       <ContractNum>123</ContractNum>
   </ContractInfo>
   <ContractInfo>
       <PledgeType>4</PledgeType>
       <ContractType>3</ContractType>
       <ContractNum>125</ContractNum>
   </ContractInfo>
   <ContractInfo>
       <PledgeType>3</PledgeType>
       <ContractType>0</ContractType>
       <ContractNum>123</ContractNum>           
   </ContractInfo>
 </MorgaginContracts>
</Root>
```

There is no identifer of repeatable nodes. How can I create in MVC project a repository with CRUD operation for "ContractInfo"? And ContractInfo may have your repeatable child node.

Any idea? How to solve many layered xmlnodes?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand this "And ContractInfo may have your repeatable child node"

if at all you want to do CRUD operations with xml,

```
using System.Xml.Linq; //Name space 

public class ContractInfo // Class for opertion - type
{
  public int PledgeType {get; set;}
  public int ContractType {get; set;}
  public int ContractNum {get; set;}
}

public class Operations
{
  public void insertContractInfo(ContractInfo obj)
  {
     XDocument contInfo = XDocument.load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/contractInfo.xml"));


     contInfo.Root.Add(new XElement("ContractInfo",
           new XElement("PledgeType", obj.PledgeType),
           new XElement("ContractType", obj.ContractType),
           new XElement("ContractNum", obj.ContractNum)
           ));
    contInfo.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/Appointments.xml"));
    string status = "success";
  }
}
```

This is just a sample piece of code to get you working. this works. For editing and update you may need to use Element("Node name").Value

Comment: <ConatractInfo>
   <PledgeType>3</PledgeType>
       <ContractType>0</ContractType>
       <ContractNum>123</ContractNum>
     <Accounts>
        <Account>
          <AccountNumber>AccNUm1</AccountNumber>
          <Amount>200</Amount>
        </Account>
                <Account>
          <AccountNumber>AccNUm2</AccountNumber>
          <Amount>200</Amount>
        </Account>
      </Accounts>
<ConatractInfo>

How can I work (CRUD operation) with child nodes "Accounts" of ContractInfo?

Comment: you cant process any random xml, if you have a defined model its easy. otherwise you would need more condtions

Comment: I have a huge xml document, which has layar of nodelist. I want work with selected "ContractInfo[contractIndex]/Accounts/Account[AccIndex]". How can I do it? I have to work with child nodes.

Comment: To say, there is no issue. If you have defined your model of xml then it may be easy to do it. provide your complete xml for one node. it may be optional but it cant vary much